# can we retrieve document revision by transaction hash in qldb

Tags: sql, blockchain, amazon-qldb, partiql

we're trying to retrieve commited document revision in qldb with its transaction hash. however it is not returning a row that has particular hash while trying below query

```
SELECT * FROM history(Users) AS h WHERE h.hash='8kmIsF2X2HonQDhuoosBbKZtSQCjHZgnyUmPGZa9pJc='
```

I believe that tx hash in qldb revision is ion literal so it should not be treated as string. so how can we retreive document revision by hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute this query successfully you'll need to treat the `hash` value as a blob type Ion literal, which can be done using backticks and`{{...}}` :

```sql
SELECT * FROM history(Users) AS h WHERE h.hash = `{{8kmIsF2X2HonQDhuoosBbKZtSQCjHZgnyUmPGZa9pJc=}}`
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.query.html#ql-reference.query.backtick

It is worth noting that this query scans every revision for all documents in the `Users` table. QLDB's
history does not support indexes and this query will degrade as the table grows.

Comment: Please avoid direct solicitations for help, especially including an e-mail address. It's only likely to result in that e-mail address getting spammed. Stack Overflow questions and answers are for all users and *future* readers... it's not a traditional forum in this sense.